# Odoo - Change name report sale_order

Tags: odoo

I want to change the name of a report and replace the existing one.
The report is that of the model sale.report_saleorder

I duplicated this template to change the name. But the basic one goes above after the one I customized. Why ?

EDIT :

[image]

Comment: You duplicated the action report, which created a new entry under Print dropdown menu. To change the report name, edit Printed Report Name of the corresponding report action under `Technical > Actions > Reports`

Comment: Hello,
I did this directly from the admin interface. However, I have the impression that does not take my file name. The result is "Quotation - SOXXX.pdf". However, I can see it clearly in the "print" of the sale.

Comment: Do you mean that the file name does not change when you print `PPF - Devis personalisé`?

Comment: Yes. The name should be "New Quotation name - SOXXX" but odoo take the report whose name is "Devis / Commande" with print name "Quotation - SOXXX"

Comment: The name of the report is the same when duplicating, so Odoo will use the report which is ranked first by ordering by the `name` field. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the report file name, Odoo will use the [reportname](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/controllers/main.py#L2130) (`sale.report_saleorder`) and `LIMIT` set to 1 to call the [search](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L494) on `ir.action.report` model, the returned result depends on the [ORDER](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L90).

If we take in consideration the `French` language, the report action names will be:

- Devis / Commande
- PPF - Devis personalisé

And the search method will return the first report listed above (which comes first when ordering by `name` field), so Odoo will use the same report file name for all reports with the same report name.

To change the report file name, you do not need to duplicate the report, just edit the report file name (Nom du rapport imprimé).

Comment: Thank you very much, I just gave it a try and just figured out the logic of the printed reports.

Answer (score 0):

To change the `sale.report_saleorder` report name, you can:

1. Create new module (custom), do not forget to inherit from the original module.
2. create xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="sale.action_report_saleorder" model="ir.actions.report">
        <field name="name">New Name Here</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
        <field name="report_name">sale.report_saleorder</field>
        <field name="report_file">sale.report_saleorder</field>
        <field name="print_report_name">(object.state in ('draft', 'sent') and 'New Quotation name - %s' % (object.name)) or 'New Order Name - %s' % (object.name)</field>
        <field name="binding_model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order"/>
        <field name="binding_type">report</field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: Hello,
I did this directly from the admin interface. However, I have the impression that does not take my file name. The result is "Quotation - SOXXX.pdf". However, I can see it clearly in the "print" of the sale.